# Dropdown SelectedItem value not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass a query string value through the url but I'm facing a problem. When I pass the dropdown value only the first value passes but other values do not pass as the url.

Here from Send Value Code:

```
protected void btnAdminReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("AdminReportView.aspx?DateFrom=" + txtDate1.Text + "&DateTo=" + txtDate2.Text + "&DrpUsrName=" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem);    
}
```

Comment: Please share more code, and the HTML page.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            strDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["DateFrom"]);
            endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["DateTo"]);
            DrpUserName = Request.QueryString["DrpUsrName"];
            string sql;
            sql = ("SELECT * FROM tblReport WHERE Date between'" + strDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'and UserName='" + DrpUserName + "'");
        }

Answer (score 0):

To get a `DropDownList`'s selected `Value`, you need to use `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`, not `SelectedItem`.

Also, use [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) for faster and more readable concatenations.

So this is what your method should look like:

```
protected void btnAdminReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string URL = string.Format("AdminReportView.aspx?DateFrom={0}&DateTo={1}&DrpUsrName={2}", 
        txtDate1.Text, 
        txtDate2.Text, 
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue);    

    Response.Redirect(URL);
}
```

Comment: You can also use string interpolation here: 

`string URL = $"AdminReportView.aspx?DateFrom={txtDate1.Text}&DateTo={txtDate2.Text}&DrpUsrName={DropDownList1.SelectedValue}";`

Comment: Still now same problem

Comment: @MethounAhmed Please edit your question and add the relevant HTML code.

Comment: Here does not use Html code.Use C# for get value from sql database.       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="298px"></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: @MethounAhmed I still need to see the HTML it could be part of the problem